# React DnD - How to make item opacity 0 when start dragging?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-dnd

Hi I have class component like this

```
const spec = {
    beginDrag(props, monitor) {
        //Toto by sa dalo nahradit ako new DnDItem ale nevezme to pretoze to musi byt plainObject
        const item = {currentContainerType: props.typeOfContainer, currentArrayPosition: props.orderInContainer};
        return item;
    },
};
const collect = (connect, monitor) => {
    return {
        connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
        connectDragPreview: connect.dragPreview(),
        isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
    };
};


class DnDSource extends React.PureComponent<IProps, IStates> {

    render() {
        const {connectDragSource} = this.props;
        return (
            connectDragSource(
                <div className={'source'} style={{opacity: (monitor.isDraging() === true) ? 0 : 1}}>
                    <TextFlowRenderer fontName={this.props.item.response.fontName}
                                      fontSize={this.props.item.response.fontSize}
                                      formulas={this.props.item.response.formulas}
                                      textToRender={this.props.item.response.response}/>
                </div>,
            )
        );
    }
}

export default DragSource('answer', spec, collect)(DnDSource);
```

This works fine unless I need to make original part opacity = 0 when start dragging this item. I am new with this libary. Please how can I do it?

As you can see I tried something like this

```
style={{opacity: (monitor.isDraging() === true) ? 0 : 1}}
```

But this not work bcs i have no access to monitor object in my component.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dragging state from the monitor:

```
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
        item,
        collect: (monitor: DragSourceMonitor) => ({
            isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
        }),
    });

    drag(ref);
    return <div ref={ref} style={{ opacity: isDragging ? 0 : 1 }}>Example</div>
```

Will set the opacity to 0 when the div is dragging.